# Parsing data with BeautifulSoup and sorting data with pandas DataFrame to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

My goal is to parse data from a website and store those data on a text file, formatted to be opened in Excel.

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pprint
import re
import pyperclip
import json
import pandas as pd
import csv

pag = range (2, 126)
out_file = open('bestumbrellasoffi.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
with open('bestumbrellasoffi.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for x in pag:

    # Iterate pages
        url = 'https://www.paginegialle.it/ricerca/lidi%20balneari/italia/p-' + str(x) + '?mr=50'
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

        # Parse data
        for i, j, k, p, z in zip(soup.find_all('span', attrs=
{'itemprop': 'name'}), soup.find_all('span', attrs=
{'itemprop': 'longitude'}), soup.find_all('span', attrs=
{'itemprop': 'latitude'}), soup.find_all('span', attrs = {'class': 'street-
address'}), soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class': 'tel elementPhone'})):
            info = i.text, j.text, k.text, p.text, z.text

            # Check if data is good
            print(url)
            print (info)

            # Create dataframe
            raw_data = { 'nome': [i], 'longitudine': [j], 'latitudine':
            [k], 'indirizzo': [p], 'telefono': [z]}
            print(raw_data)
            df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns =
               ['nome', 'longitudine', 'latitudine', 'indirizzo', 'telefono'])
            df.to_csv('bestumbrellasoffi.txt')

out_file.close()
```

There are all those modules because I made many tries.

So the output of

```
print(info)  [is][1]
```

The output of

print(raw_data)   [is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbXqT.png)

---

This is the code reviewed and perfectly functioning.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pprint
import re
import pyperclip
import json
import pandas as pd
import csv

pag = range (2, 126)
with open('bestumbrellasoffia.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:

    for x in pag:

    # Iterate pages
        url = 'https://www.paginegialle.it/ricerca/lidi%20balneari/italia/p-' + str(x) + '?mr=50'
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        raw_data = { 'nome': [], 'longitudine': [], 'latitudine': [], 'indirizzo': [], 'telefono': []}
        df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['nome', 'longitudine', 'latitudine', 'indirizzo', 'telefono'])

        # Parse data
        for i, j, k, p, z in zip(soup.find_all('span', attrs = {'itemprop': 'name'}), soup.find_all('span', attrs = {'itemprop': 'longitude'}), soup.find_all('span', attrs = {'itemprop': 'latitude'}), soup.find_all('span', attrs = {'class': 'street-address'}), soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class': 'tel elementPhone'})):
            inno = i.text.lstrip()
            ye = inno.rstrip()
            info = ye, j.text, k.text, p.text, z.text

            # Check if data is good
            print(info)

            # Create dataframe
            raw_data = { 'nome': [i], 'longitudine': [j], 'latitudine': [k], 'indirizzo': [p], 'telefono': [z]}

            # Try dataframe
            #print(raw_data)
            file.write(str(info) + "\n")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What is the question?  Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Comment: thank you @wwii, and sorry for being unclear

Answer (score 0):

You're initialising a new Data Frame every iteration of your for loop.

You should initialise it outside the loop then use append() in your loop to add each row of data.

Comment: thank you this helped! I'm editing the question with the code working :)